# DBContext does not contain a definition for Entry: Cannot load related data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

When trying to load related data and following the guide on [Explicit Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit), I get the following error:

> IApplicationDbcontext does not contain a definition for `Entry`.

My example code, similar to theirs, includes:

```
var person = _context.Persons.Single(p => p.PersonId = id);
_context.Entry(person).Collection(p => p.Addresses).Load();
```

The difference in my case is that I am injecting an `IApplicationDbContext` which looks pretty standard and I assume doesn't make a difference:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
   ...
   public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

I have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.7` within this project.

Comment: `Entry` is a virtual method of the `DbContext` class, if your `_context` is `IApplicationContext` then it won't be available to be called.   https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/106ac1ab4f0948ad52ca7318d376b1def9148321/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs#L915

Comment: @Lowkey Woah, really? Injecting an application's db context has been the norm for a long time. How could this not work? Are relational properties useless then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IApplicationDbContext` must declare the following method signiture in it in order to work.

```
EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>([NotNullAttribute] TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
```